# load JSON in unordered list with $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm trying to get a list on my website with the latest Jobs available, I have a good JSON file put it's hard to get it into the unordered list. I'm trying it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$.getJSON("my_url",

              function(data) {
                $('#li-1a').empty();
                $.each(data[0], function(i,item){
                  $("<a/>").html(data[0].ContractTitle).appendTo("#li-1a");
                });
              });

        });
```

But this won't work, if I do this it  repeats the ContractTitle for several times, I think it's because of the `$.each`

How can I do this in another way?

Here is the JSON file:

```
            [
                {
                    "ContractID": 14,
                    "ContractTitle": "Projectmanager",
                    "ContractStatus": "Closed",
                    "Executionlocation": "Utrecht",                    
                },
                {
                    "ContractID": 8,
                    "ContractTitle": "Projectmedewerker",
                    "ContractStatus": "Open",
                    "Executionlocation": "Aspen",                    
                },
                {
                    "ContractID": 7,
                    "ContractTitle": "Projectmanager",
                    "ContractStatus": "Closed",
                    "Executionlocation": "Delft",
                 },
            ]
```

And the unordered list html code:

```
                         <ul class="list-1" id="ul-1">
                           <li id="li-1a"></li>
                           <li id="li-2a"></li>
                           <li id="li-3a"></li>
                         </ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `item` instead of `data[0]`:

```
   $.getJSON("my_url", function(data) {
       $('#li-1a').empty();
       $.each(data, function(i,item){
          $("<a/>").html(item.ContractTitle).appendTo("#li-1a");
       });
   });
```

It also might be a better idea to use `jQuery.text` as it prevents xss:

```
$("<a/>").appendTo("#li-1a").text(item.ContractTitle);
```

Comment: You are very welcome :) - if you have a lot of this kind of content rendering you might want to check out a templating engine like handlebars

Answer (score -1):

Look like you wanted:

```
   $.each(data[0], function(i,item){
          $("<a/>").html(item.ContractTitle).appendTo("#li-1a");
   });
```

item instead of data[0]

Comment: This doesn't gives me anything at all, the other code works for me

Comment: I didn't write the full code. Only the line I changed and the lines around it. The rest was correct. Glad you got it sorted though